# Actioncable in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, rails-engines, actioncable

I am making engine for real time chat in rails. I am not able to figure out how to use actioncable in it. I am trying to implement in the same way as it is done in rails app by making channel and subscribing to channel but it is not working in my rails engine. There is not any guide on this topic as well. I will be grateful if someone could guide me in this regard.

Comment: You do realize that an engine must be mounted in a application?

Comment: Yes i do know but should i make channels in my rails engine or application?

Comment: It depends on if the channels are functionality that can be shared across multiple Rails applications. If not why bother placing them in an engine? If have not tried using channels in an engine but I can't imagine that its any different than components like controllers.

Comment: @Maueez - did you make any progress with this? I'm currently looking at a similar issue and wondering if you found a solution.

Comment: yes. I was able to make rails engine. Do you have any specific issue? @Jon

Comment: Yeah, I want to add ActionCable code in a rails engine, which then works in the Rails app which mounts it

Comment: @Maueez I'm also trying to develop a chat app in rails engine and facing issue the issue with action cable. can you let me know what issue you were facing & how you solved it? It might be that i'm also facing the same issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look here: https://github.com/palkan/engine-cable-app

There's a fully working example with 2 cables, one from the engine and second from the app itself.